# Is there a generic way to refer to the current function in recursion?

Tags: functional-programming, recursion, lambda

In writing recursive functions (functional style), I often need to refer to the current function (depending on the context).
e.g.

```
f 0  = 0
f (S n) = f n + 2
```

*Are there any functional languages that allow using a generic name such as `this_function` or `self` to be used instead of the specific function name `f`?*

So, hypothetically, the above would be rewritten as

```
f 0  = 0
f (S n) = self n + 2
```

It seems to make the spot of recursion easier to identify and the intention clearer. Also, it seems to allow one to [write recursive anonymous functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141229), e.g. a function to double a number in pseudo-code:

```
\n r -> if n > 0 then self (n - 1) (r + 2) else r
```

*Does such facility exist or is it possible?*

Comment: I actually think this obfuscates the meaning more than clarifies it. I don't generally make a recursive call *because* it's a recursive call. For instance, when I write `append`, I make a call to `append` because I've done some of the work and now I need to append two lists. The fact that it happens to be the same function is almost a coincidence. If it were a different fn that also appended it'd still work. I just need to ensure I make progress. This is often how I think about recursion: "do some of the work, then treat the function 'as though it already works' when making recursive calls"

Comment: That perspective also naturally extends to mutually recursive functions, even when there are more than two functions involved.

Comment: I can only see this being useful for anonymous functions, e.g. `(n) => n <= 1 ? n : this_function(n-1) + this_function(n-2)` in Javascript. Otherwise making "the spot of recursion easier to identify" just isn't that important; IDE's can already highlight uses of a function's name when you hover over one of them (including the name in the function definition).

Comment: One issue is that you have to be very careful about a sort of dual of scoping. In many languages, `\n r -> ...` can best be understood as syntactic sugar for `\n -> \r -> ...`. But your example, `\n r -> ... self (n-1) (r+2) ...` relies critically on `\n r -> ...` and `\n -> \r -> ...` having distinct meanings. Or consider `f x = if x > 0 then (\n -> ...self...) else (\n -> 3)`; here you must decide whether `self` should refer to just the inner `\n -> ...` or to the entire `f x = ...`. Of course all of these decisions *can* be made, it just may be more complicated than you first think.

Comment: I agree with all these potential limitations, e.g. on mutual recursion, scoping and the implicitness. It's just an idea that occurred to me, and I was wondering it's being around.

Comment: New here, so please forgive my ignorance and with no disrespect to OP who obviously knows a lot more than me, but I don't understand the question. Every language I code in has implicit ways to identify the methods being called. Happy for comments here or PM / chat if someone can help explain. Thanks.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://qntm.org/y

Comment: @Absinthe by definition, a recursive function is one that calls itself. But in order to specify what "itself" is, the code for that function will typically include a *name* for itself, which then has to be *looked up in an enclosing scope* (possibly the global scope). In OP's example in Haskell syntax, the recursively-defined `f` has code that includes the symbol `f` itself. The goal is to make this recursive call *without relying on* the name. So, for example, it should be possible to rename the function and still have it work and make those recursive calls, without changing the code inside.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I agree. The function name should be a single point of truth, there should be no need to repeat it everywhere. It should also be optional: anonymous functions should be able to recurse.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### APL

A few APL dialects support the glyph `∇` inside a dfn (which is pretty much a lambda) which refers to the dfn itself. See [Dyalog documentation on recursion](https://help.dyalog.com/latest/#Language/Defined%20Functions%20and%20Operators/DynamicFunctions/Recursion.htm).

(I guess it depends if you consider APL a functional language or not, tbf it doesn't have a lot of features standard FP languages are supposed to have)

Comment: Thanks. The `Implicit self-reference using '∇' ` APL counts though I don't know the language.

Answer (score 7):

#### Forth

Recursion in Forth actually requires a construct like this, as a word is not visible inside its own definition.  In order to recurse, you need to use the [`recurse`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Calls-and-returns.html#index-recurse-_0040var_007b-compilation-_002d_002d-_003b-run_002dtime-_003f_003f-_002d_002d-_003f_003f---_007d--core-1143) word, like so:

```
: factorial ( n -- n! )
    dup 0> if
        dup 1- recurse *
    else
        drop 1
    endif
;
```

Answer (score 5):

In Perl — which is not *primarily* a functional language, but does *support* functional programming styles — the keyword `__SUB__` is a reference to the current subroutine; your last example could be written as

```
sub { my ($n, $r) = @_; $n > 0 ? __SUB__->($n-1, $r+2) : $r }
```

Wikipedia refers to this as *[anonymous recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_recursion#Examples)*, and in addition to Perl and APL, it also mentions equivalent features in JavaScript and R.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I just noticed it today and it covers all of the languages mentioned thus far except for Mathematica. Maybe we can update the Wiki page?

Answer (score 4):

Mathematica, a definition of the factorial function:

```
If[#1 == 1, 1, #1 #0[#1 - 1]]&
```

(The ampersand indicates a definition of an anonymous function; `#0` is the anonymous function itself, and `#1` is the first argument to that function.)

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript, [`arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee) could be used, but it is now deprecated and invalid in strict mode.

```js
function f(n) { return n === 0 ? 0 : arguments.callee(n-1) + 2; }
```

Comment: Doesn't this work by inspecting the runtime stack, rather than being an actual syntactic feature?

Comment: I think so, but I still wanted to comment because JS is widely-used.

Answer (score 3):

In `R` we have `Recall`. From the docs we see (calling `?Recall`):

> `Recall` is used as a placeholder for the name of the function in which it is called. It allows the definition of recursive functions which still work after being renamed, see example below.

```r
## A trivial (but inefficient!) example:
fib <- function(n)
   if(n<=2) { if(n>=0) 1 else 0 } else Recall(n-1) + Recall(n-2)
fibonacci <- fib; rm(fib)
## renaming wouldn't work without Recall
fibonacci(10) # 55
```

Answer (score 3):

#### C++

Since C++23 you can add an [explicit object parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Parameter_list) to member functions and lambdas. You still have to give the parameter a name, but you would typically use `self` for that argument:

```
auto factorial = [](this auto self, int n) -> int {
    return n > 1 ? n * self(n - 1) : 1;
}
```